# prevent camel from initializing the endpoint

Tags: apache-camel

I have an endpoint in the route that cannot be instatiated locally - due to some missing properties that are unavailable and cannot be accessed in the local environment.

So when I start the application in local environment I get the error `org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException`. However in server environment it works fine.

**How to prevent camel from initializing endpoint on the local environment** (I have a property that allows to find out whether the environent is local or not)? Something like this

```
<choice>
    <when>
        <simple>{{is.local}} == true</simple>
        <to uri="direct:local.route"/>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <to uri="direct:server.route"/>
    </otherwise>
</choice>
```

But for `from` clause

Comment: I think you should not modify your camel context to handle a local execution. I think you should use multiple camel context with a profile management or properties configuration instead

Comment: @MickaëlB but will it help with endpoints?

Comment: Yes it is. In your case, I think the properties would be the most relevant solution. So you can define route like `<to uri="{{property.route}}"/>` and determine the value in a configuration file.

Comment: @MickaëlB or I can even avoid the definition of route at all?

Comment: I don't know what your route is doing but it's unlikely. The point is to avoid the choice configuration.

Comment: @MickaëlB I posted the answer. I moved routes loading into the profiles so basically created two route definitions - one for local, one - for any other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the idea of *MickaëlB* to use profiles, I did like this.

I created `camel-route-local.xml` and `camel-route.xml`. First file contains routes that should work in the local environment. Second - routes that operates with endpoints that are not for local environment. File `camel-context.xml` contains `camelContext` definition definition.

In my main `application-context.xml` I added these line at the end of the file

```
 <beans profile="default">
    <import resource="classpath:camel-route.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:camel-context.xml"/>
 </beans>

<beans profile="LOCAL">
    <import resource="classpath:camel-route-local.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:camel-context.xml"/>
</beans>
```

Now, if I run local environment - aka set `spring` profile as `LOCAL` - it will load `camel-route-local.xml` with routes that works for local environment (also I got of rid the check for `is.local`) and if the environment is not `LOCAL` - aka any other profile - it will load main routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java DSL for this part only (create simple RouteBuilder) and initialize required "from" part depending on anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is "better" alternative solution. Why don't you inject your parameters as environment variables. Then inject those as properties and you can use use Camel's property resolver to inject the properties in your `from()` or `to()`.

See here under "propertyinject"
http://camel.apache.org/properties.html